# So i just replaced kitchen faucet and now no water to dishwasher. I did not turn off the dishwasher hot water valve only one going to faucet

Tags: kitchens, faucet, dishwasher, kitchen-sink

After replacing kitchen faucet my dishwasher is now not working I only turned off the hot water line and cold water lines to the faucet there is an extra shut off valve to the dishwasher which I did not touch trying to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Is dishwasher shut off before or after faucets shut off?  If faucets are working, possible something(goop, solder) came loose and is blocking the dish washer line.  Turn off dishwasher valve and undo line to see if water comes out(into a bucket).

Comment: So didn't have to use goop will undoing redoing line. Tried turning valve to dw off then on the on didn't help. Will remove line and check water flow hoping not to have to pull dw. 62 yrs old lady this is getting out of my comfort zone and not much on you tube to help lol